# JMS Queue and JMS Topic

Tags: jms

How a Queue and Topic can be applied in airport management when a plane arrives?

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise on what you want to do exactly? - Do you already have an application that generates messages, what exactly do you want to achieve, ....

Comment: In general how a JMS queue and JMS topic be used in an airport management when a plane arrives? It is just a open ended question.

Comment: Either an airport asked the wrong guy to develop their system, or someone's asking us to do their homework :-P

Answer (score 4):

At the airport there are many systems that interact with the plane at ramp time.  These include fueling and servicing the plane, gate management, passenger announcements, FAA filings, and 3rd party vendors such as those who SMS you with updates.  All of these are different families of applications both within and  external to the airport's network fabric.

Publishing a single event notification on a topic is a good way to update all interested systems at once.  Rather than establishing dozens of point-to-point interfaces for all these systems, they are all allowed to subscribe to the topic of interest.  The publications can be converted to queued delivery on a per-receiver basis for legacy apps or external apps that cannot issue a subscribe command.